# Running other subs after TimerProc finishes every X seconds (API SetTimer in Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, timer, vba

I'm using the Windows API timer in excel for a VBA project (sort of a beginner with VBA) and while investigating why Excel keeps crashing, I thought of this question.

In macro with several subs, the first sub starts the timer which will run the TimerProc code, say every 5 seconds. After starting the timer, the first sub finishes and the next begins. Other functions are called in the second sub and the program finishes before that 5 seconds on the Timer is reached. So technically the entire macro is complete by the time TimerProc is called.

At this point, **is it possible to run / call any other part of any other sub or function AFTER the TimerProc code ends?** Obviously you can make calls while in the TimerProc code, but how about after it's over? For example, if KillTimer is executed in the TimerProc, but I don't restart the timer in the TimerProc, is there a way to restart the timer somewhere else?

Note: I'm using the method of calling Windows Timers detailed in http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Attempted Example:

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single

Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 10000 ' how often to "pop" the timer, in milliseconds
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    'On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    timerFinished = True
    Call EndTimer
    'Instead of calling StartTimer here inside TimerProc, I want to exit TimerProc and re-run the below sub, which will now call StartTimer

End Sub
```

**Sub**

```
Sub exampleSub ()

    Call StartTimer

    If timerFinished = True Then
        Msgbox "It worked!"
        call StartTimer
    End If        
End Sub
```

The timer is currently set to 10 seconds, and the example Sub will most definitely have finished running before that 10 seconds hits and TimerProc is able to run and changes the timerFinished bool to True. Is there a way to, once TimerProc finishes, re-run the exampleSub (now that timerFinished is True) to restart the timer **without** calling StartTime in the TimerProc itself? I want to make sure the TimerProc completely ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch `exampleSub` after TimerProc` finishes, you can use:

```
Application.OnTime Now, "exampleSub"
```

The above statement instructs VBA to start `exampleSub` **as soon as possible**, after the current processing (all routines currently in the call stack) is finished.

By the way, you can use an `Application.OnTime` loop to solve your original problem without the need for the `SetTimer` API. The latter is only interesting if you need timing in milliseconds, while the unit of `OnTime` is one second.

Comment: A.S.H thank you for the response. Where would I put 'Application.OnTime Now, "exampleSub"' in the program? If I put it anywhere outside of TimerProc, how will the program know when to go back to it after TimerProc is called? Also, I do indeed need more resolution than seconds for my timing, specifically tenths of a seconds.

Comment: @jdyagoda I guess at the place of your comment *"Instead of calling StartTimer here inside TimerProc, I want to exit TimerProc and re-run the below sub, which will now call StartTimer"*. The statement will do exactly that: `exampleSub` is lauched as soon as the `TimerProc` returns (it wont be present in the call stack anymore).

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in the `exampleSub`, and display the call stack. you can verify that nothing is above it... apart the VBA runtime...

Comment: Apologies for taking a bit to mark this. This did in fact work to call a different subroutine specifically after the 'TimerProc' code finishes. Thanks very much! Unfortunately, excel still crashed repeatedly so I did eventually have to switch it up.

Comment: @jdyagoda glad to help. If you are getting other problems when using `OnTime`, I encourage you to post the updated code and ask another question. Any code that makes Excel "crash" is excellent candidate for some investigation on SO :). By the way I wonder if there's a conflict between `SetTimer` and `Ontime`, very curious to know more.